# additional field not showing in django admin panel

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    contact = models.CharField(max_length=17,null=True)
```

whenever i tried to add a user through Djangoo admin site the contact field is not showing

```
class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = '__all__'


class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = '__all__'

class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_form = CustomUserCreationForm
    form = CustomUserChangeForm
    model = CustomUser
    list_display = ['username', 'email', 'is_staff', 'is_admin','department_id','company_id',]
    list_filter = ['is_staff', 'is_admin']
    fieldsets = UserAdmin.fieldsets + (
        (None, {'fields': ('is_admin','department_id','company_id','contact',)}),
    )
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', 'is_admin','department_id','company_id',),
        }),
    )
```

this is what i used to add field , i tried most of the thing to add this fields to Django user admin but not showing is there any mistake in my code

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the field to the `add_fieldset`, as well as the `fieldsets` when you want to enable to change it, with:

```
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_form = CustomUserCreationForm
    form = CustomUserChangeForm
    model = CustomUser
    list_display = [
        'username',
        'email',
        'is_staff',
        'is_admin',
        'department_id',
        'company_id',
    ]
    list_filter = ['is_staff', 'is_admin']
    fieldsets = UserAdmin.fieldsets[1:] + (
        (
            None,
            {
                'fields': (
                    'username',
                    'password',
                    'is_admin',
                    'department_id',
                    'company_id',
                    'contact',
                )
            },
        ),
    )
    add_fieldsets = (
        (
            None,
            {
                'classes': ('wide',),
                'fields': (
                    'username',
                    'email',
                    'password1',
                    'password2',
                    'is_admin',
                    'department_id',
                    'company_id',
                    'contact',
                ),
            },
        ),
    )
```

That being said, it is unclear why you added an `is_admin`, since Django already has a field for this: [**`is_superuser`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_superuser).